# How to make web game canvas fit the window

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have a web game and I'm doing this to fit the game to the window:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now when I scale the browser window, it just stretches the game.

This is the full sized browser:

[image]

This is what happens when I scale browser window:

[image]

My question: when I scale the browser window instead of stretching the game I want it to zoom in. like this:

This is what I want to happen when I scale the browser window:

[image]

Comment: You may need something like keeping an aspect ratio between height and width. Have a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp

Comment: **1)** Don't use CSS to style canvas; use `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` in JS. **2)** I don't see that your final example is "zoomed in" in any way. I see that the top and bottom are cropped. You can set the canvas width and height to anything fixed and this is what you'll get. Do you want it to be initially set to the window width and height dynamically, but remained fixed regardless of resizing?

Comment: @ggorlen yes you are right I should have said crop instead of zoom. for better understanding please see [this](https://gyazo.com/94a41e06816b8dc9a1fd4608c0cfa525)

Comment: The linked image appears to involve zooming as well as cropping? I'll post an answer that only crops, and let me know if that's not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment and sample result image, it sounds like you want the `<canvas>` game element to fill the entire screen with no margin on load. The below code creates a canvas, draws your pattern onto it (more or less) scaled to the window proportions, and maintains those proportions regardless of any resizing that may occur:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

/* 
 * These width and height values are set once on load, 
 * then remain fixed and will not change after window resizing 
 */
canvas.width = document.body.scrollWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;

ctx.fillStyle = "#744";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

ctx.fillStyle = "#700";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(
  canvas.width / 2, 
  canvas.height / 2, 
  canvas.width / 30, 
  0, Math.PI * 2
);
ctx.fill();

ctx.strokeStyle = "#711";
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.strokeRect(
  canvas.width / 6, 
  canvas.height / 6, 
  canvas.width / 1.5, 
  canvas.height / 1.5
);

ctx.strokeStyle = "#711";
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.strokeRect(
  canvas.width / 3, 
  canvas.height / 3, 
  canvas.width / 3, 
  canvas.height / 3
);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1rsfyj8p/15/).

For reference, if you wish the image to adjust to fit the viewport upon resizing or maintain a fixed aspect ratio, attach an event listener on the `"resize"` event and set `canvas.width`/`height` based on the updated window `innerWidth`/`innerHeight` properties. Look into [debouncing](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) to prevent this resize event from firing excessively and hogging the CPU.

The difficulty in implementing any dynamic resizing (or even calculating all the dimensions once on page load as done above) is that you'll need your game data to be responsive/scalable as well, and the stretching effect may be undesirable (i.e. if the user's original aspect ratio is something weird, your game will appear stretched and unplayable).

Comment: Thank you so much, that will do

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is to maintain an aspect ratio.

In order to do this, you still have to declare width and height at 100% but also a top padding for eg ratio of 16:9 like below:

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    padding-top: 56.25%; /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio */
}
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp

See it working here: https://jsbin.com/gajumuq/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

You could try experimenting with the css units vh and vw, these set the size based on the height or width of the browser. For example:

```css
 body {
    margin: 0;
}
 div {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

In this example when you make the browser small vertically it scales proportionally. (resizing in the browser in this example doesn't work because this is an iframe but try it out for yourself and see that it works).

Here is an example in which you can see it in action:

https://jsbin.com/rununuxara/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

If you want the canvas to completely cover the window, but at the same time maintain the aspect ratio, then you can do this.

*I can advise you to also read [this article](https://gmer.io/c/t/learning_to_do_full_screen_canvas_html).*

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");

var aspectRatio = 16/9; //ratio as you want, for example 16:9

function refreshCanvas() {//refresh size canvas function
  if (window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight >= aspectRatio) {
    canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth+'px';
    canvas.style.height = (window.innerWidth/aspectRatio)+'px';
  } else if (window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight < aspectRatio) {
    canvas.style.width = (window.innerHeight*aspectRatio)+'px';
    canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight+'px';
  }
  canvas.style.left = (window.innerWidth/2-canvas.offsetWidth/2)+'px';
  canvas.style.top = (window.innerHeight/2-canvas.offsetHeight/2)+'px';
}

window.addEventListener('resize', refreshCanvas); //refresh when resize window
window.addEventListener('load', refreshCanvas); //refresh when load window
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#mycanvas {
  position: fixed;
  background-image: url('https://gmer.io/resource/community/backgroundCanvas.png');
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```